# Binding to two different DataContexts in a ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datatemplate

I'm trying to bind to a property of a container from inside a DataTemplate.  A simplified version of my markup looks like:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type myCustomItem}">

    <!--Visual stuff-->

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Add Item" 
                          Command="{Binding myCustomItemsICommand}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CustomContainerType}}, Path=ContainerProperty}"/>   
            </ContextMenu>
         </StackPanel.ContextMenu>   
     </StackPanel>                                                            
</DataTemplate>

</Grid.Resources>

<CustomContainerType/>

</Grid>
```

My approach is based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702987/outside-property-inside-a-datatemplate-wpf) but it doesn't seem to be working.  The issue seems to arise from the placement of the ContextMenu within the visual tree.  Basically I am trying to bind the Command to the DataContext of the DataTemplate but bind the CommandParameter to a DataContext outside the DataTemplate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContextMenus` are not in the same visual tree as the rest of the controls, there are a few questions regarding how to do bindings accross that boundary but this might be somewhat difficult without specifying names.

`ElementName` fails as well because of the lacking tree connection, but you could use [`x:Reference`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795380.aspx) in the `Binding.Source` instead.

Comment: Thanks!  The `Source={x:Reference Name=theElementName}` approach worked.